# directory on `ls -l` showing `?` on most of the details

Tags: mount, sshfs

I have shared a tmp directory on Ubuntu, using `sshfs userid@ip:path_to_dir/rdir /path_to_dir/tmp` after this I deleted `rdir` but when I tried `umount /path_to_dir/tmp` it was unable to do that. 
Now whenever I do ls it shows

```
ls: cannot access 'tmp': No such file or directory
check.cpp                 tmp
```

and output of `ls -al` is really weird

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 userid   userid          84 Oct  5 12:49 check.cpp
d?????????  ? ?        ?               ?            ? tmp
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and how can I unmount this directory properly
I don't know the proper tags. Please add proper tags so it reaches to the right person.
Thanks in advance

`EDIT`

```
pranjald@pranjald-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ mount | grep tmp
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16383840k,nr_inodes=4095960,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3281548k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3281544k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
pranjald@11.22.33.44:/home/pranjald/Desktop/rdir on /home/pranjald/Desktop/tmp type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

```
pranjald@pranjald-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo fusermount -u tmp
fusermount: failed to unmount /home/pranjald/Desktop/tmp: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `mount | grep tmp`. Also, does `sudo fusermount -u /path_to_dir/tmp` unmount it?

Comment: @terdon I've updated the question with suggested output.

Comment: Quite strange. On a different GNU/Linux I could reproduce your issue (same `mount` output, same `ls` output after deleting the directory underlying the mount point), but both `fusermount -u /path/to/tmp` and `sudo umount /path/to/tmp` did unmount successfully. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @fra-san I am using 18.04

Comment: @fra-san what command you use to unmount the directory? For me umount shows Command not found.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi I used the commands from my previous comment. You should have `umount` on Ubuntu, it's from the `mount` package, which should be installed by default. Same thing for `fusermount` from the `fuse` package.